# Why does the NextJs react-i18-next package work in local but not in production, and common content is empty?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, i18next, react-i18next

Why does the NextJs react-i18-next package work in local but not in production, and common content is empty? react-i18next doesn't work.

Local Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QunVw.png

Prod Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kqby.png

**This is my next-i18next.config.js file:**

```
/** @type {import('next-i18next').UserConfig} */
module.exports = {
  fallbackLng: 'tr',
  supportedLngs: ['tr', 'en'],
  load: 'languageOnly',
  ns: ['common'],
  nonExplicitSupportedLngs: true,
  defaultNS: 'common',
  i18n: {
    locales: ['tr', 'en'],
    defaultLocale: 'tr',
    localeDetection: false
  },
  fallbackLng: {
    default: ['tr'],
  }, 
}
```

**This is my next.config.js file:**

```
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config')
const { loadEnvConfig } = require('@next/env')

const projectDir = process.cwd()
loadEnvConfig(projectDir)

/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    ...i18n,
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
  generateEtags: false,
  poweredByHeader: false,
  productionBrowserSourceMaps: false,
  compress: false,
  swcMinify: true,
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  },
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"]
    });

    return config;
  }
}
```

I tried changes to my config files, but nothing worked. I expect my translations to work in production as well.